# Fabric Crashlytics for multiple environments - Android

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

After digging in farbic docs alot and exploring multiple stack overflow questions I don't see any information on how to setup Fabric crashlytics for dev(beta) and production both.

Basically I want beta build to log events on separate Fabric app and production build to log on different Fabric app.

Currently Fabric puts its api key in manifest which I think can be controlled for multiple environments but they put secret key in app->fabric.properties file which I don't see can be overridden for different environments.

Any help will be appreciated if someone has achieved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. Fabric lets you separate by bundle ID or package name OR API key. If you alter either of these between your build types it'll report to a separate dashboard.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out after 2 days using different bundleId.

Comment: Thank you for this Q&A. I was trying to get another API key so I have three dashboards (release, beta, debug). However, it seems like there is no option in fabric to generate a new API key. How did you solve this ? (Currently I use an applicationIdSuffix, which requires a lot of refactoring).